# Django class based DetailView/ListView ajax decorator?

Tags: python, ajax, django

**1**
Is there a conveinient way to ajax decorate generic class based views?

**2**
Is there a different approach for ListViews compared to DetailViews?

i.e.

```
if not request.is_ajax():
   raise Http404
```

Comment: I roughly understand the first question, barely the second, and am fully confused by your example. Care to elaborate? :)

Comment: The example is how I implement non ajax requests catching for function based views.. I am trying to accomplish the same for class based views

Comment: Have a look at https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/class-based-views/#more-than-just-html

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To decorate all class based views, decorate the `dispatch` method.

```
class MyView(View):
    @decorate
    def dispatch(self, *args, **kwargs):
        return super(MyView, self).dispatch(*args, **kwargs)
```